# Changing color of a linestring (json) in Leaflet

Tags: json, leaflet

The problem is that I see only 1 color (blue) in the map but I want to give a specific color for my levee json file. Could someone give me advice how I can change the color of the linestring?

```
var geojson = L.geoJson(null,{
  pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
    return L.circleMarker(latlng, geojsonMarkerOptions);
  }
}).addTo(map);
            var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhttp.open('GET', encodeURI("NA.json"));

geojson data to the layer when request is succesfull
            xhttp.onload = function() {
              if (xhttp.readyState === 4) {

                geojson.addData(JSON.parse(xhttp.responseText));
                } else {
                  alert('Request failed.  Returned status of ' + xhttp.status);
                }
            };


            xhttp.send();
```

**The json file**

```
  "type" : "FeatureCollection",
  "crs" : {
    "type" : "name",
    "properties" : {
      "name" : "EPSG:4326"
    }
  },
  "features" : [
    {
      "type" : "Feature",
      "id" : 122,
      "geometry" : {
        "type" : "LineString",
        "coordinates" :
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the [`style`](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.3.4.html#geojson-style) option of `L.GeoJSON`. Let me quote the [documentation](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.3.4.html#geojson-style):

> A `Function` defining the [`Path` options](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.3.4.html#path-option) for styling GeoJSON lines and polygons, called internally when data is added. The default value is to not override any defaults:
>
> ```
> function (geoJsonFeature) {
>     return {}
> }
> ```

You can apply colours to a path (a `L.Polyline` or a `L.Circle` or a `L.Polygon`) by providing a value for the `color` option. Therefore, you should provide a `style` callback function which returns a set of options including `color`:

```
var geojson = L.geoJson(null,{
  pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
    return L.circleMarker(latlng, geojsonMarkerOptions);
  },
  style: function(){
    return { color: 'pink' }
  }
}).addTo(map);
```

Please note there are further examples in the [Leaflet GeoJSON tutorial](https://leafletjs.com/examples/geojson/).